# sub differential calculation

Tags: convex-optimization

I would like to use the sub gradient method on the rotated second order cone function:

$f(x) = \partial\|Q^Tx\|_2^2$.

So, I would like to find out what the sub differential $\partial f(x)$ is:

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: My solution is $\partial \|Q^Tx\|_2^2 = 2 \|Q^Tx\|_2 \partial \|Q^Tx\|$. I am not sure how to work out the rest.